# Why is the search filter in List View not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview

I have created a List View and I added a Edit Text to it so I can search the list but its not returning anything, I have an adapter that's displaying all the data like the number of channels,the images and the title.

**The adapter:**

```
adapterEPG = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.playlistitemwithimg, arrClPlaylist) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (arrClPlaylist.get(position).nbtries < 1) {
                    convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.playlistitemwithimg, null);
                } else {
                    convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.playlistitem_warning, null);
                }
                TextView num = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number);
                TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.playlistitem);
                ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewChannel);

                MainActivity.imageloader.displayImage(String.valueOf(arrClPlaylist.get(position).logo),img, MainActivity.options);
                name.setText(arrClPlaylist.get(position).service_name);
                num.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));
                if (firstTimeStartup && position == channelIndex) {
                    //This is the first time we open the menu, and the iterator reached the previously chosen channel
                    initialChosenPosition = position;
                    //Highlight the background
                    name.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(PlayerWatchNowActivityVLC.this, R.color.primary_dark));
                } else if (!firstTimeStartup && position == initialChosenPosition) { //This is not the first time the menu opens, and the iterator reached the initially chosen channel
                    //Return background to original state
                    name.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(PlayerWatchNowActivityVLC.this, R.color.primary_dark));
                }
                //Force a refresh after fixing the appropriate background
                return convertView;
            }

        };
        controls_container.setAdapter(adapterEPG);
```

The etSearch is the EditText which I am doing this to use the filter

```
        etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                time.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                PlayerWatchNowActivityVLC.this.adapterEPG.getFilter().filter(charSequence);

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

I followed this tutorial:[link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-search-functionality-in-custom-list-view-in-android)

What I think is happening that the search is not being used on the title

Inside the adapter is (Inside the debugger):
The service_name is the title

```
mObjects = {ArrayList@5817}  size = 21
 0 = {ClPlaylist@5944} 
  is_multicast = "0"
  is_watermark = "0"
  logo = "http://exemple.com/media/services_thumbs/NatGeo.png"
  logo_big = "http://exemple.com/media/services_thumbs/NatGeo.png"
  nbtries = 0
  service_id = "5acf5bfb4e44941"
  service_name = "National Geographic"
  url = "http://dst.exemple.com/5acf5bfb4e44941/_definst_/smil:myStream_stb.smil/playlist.m3u8?t=5f45137c4f845"
  shadow$_klass_ = {Class@4721} "class com.exemple.objects.ClPlaylist"
  shadow$_monitor_ = -2072218533
 1 = {ClPlaylist@5945} 
 2 = {ClPlaylist@5946} 
 3 = {ClPlaylist@5947} 
 4 = {ClPlaylist@5948} ...
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you!